# How to get dynamic result from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following method in C#:

```
public IList<dynamic> GetDynamicPosition(String Market_ID, String UserProfile_ID)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        MyDynamic = Context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("exec GetDynamicPosition @UserID, @MarketID",
                new SqlParameter("@UserID", (object)UserProfile_ID ?? DBNull.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@MarketID", (object)Market_ID ?? DBNull.Value)).ToList();
        return MyDynamic;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When I execute this method, I get a result like this:

[image]

I want this dynamic result to serialize to Json, and when I do this code with for example

```
 var b = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

I get this result:

[image]

Remember I have 6 rows returned by the stored procedure, but with empty object property

Comment: Are you sure the six rows returned from the DB are not empty objects?